# How to compare 4 integers and return their variable names?

Tags: java

I recently started taking a Java course in my school. I'm doing a homework about a tournament, each contestant has various talents.

I'm at the last part of the question, which is comparing final points of 4 contestants to each other. We've only covered basic stuff to this date and that does not include arrays and such. We only know defining methods, basic comparison and a few things more (I'll give further detail if necessary) and I can't complete the task with these tools.

Task is comparing final points of all 4 contestants then finding top 3 among them.

We are allowed to use Math library so I tried using Math.max() among points but I can't which value comes from which contestant, then I brute forced my way through and now it doesn't work, it just returns 0.

nID = Ranking among top 3
nPoints = Points of ranking n

```
if(totalPoint1 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint1 = firstPoint;
            firstID = 1;    
        }
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = firstPoint;
            firstID = 2;    
        }
        if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = firstPoint;
            firstID = 3;    
        }
        if(totalPoint4 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint1) {
            totalPoint4 = firstPoint;
            firstID = 4;    
        }
        //Find second value
        //1 is second
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint1 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 1;   
        }
        if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint1 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 1;   
        }
        if(totalPoint4 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint1 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 1;   
        }
        //2 is second
        if(totalPoint1 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 2;   
        }
        if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 2;   
        }
        if(totalPoint4 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint2 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 2;   
        }
        //3 is second
        if(totalPoint1 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 3;   
        }
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 3;
        }
        if(totalPoint4 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint1) {
            totalPoint3 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 3;
        }
        //4 is second
        if(totalPoint1 > totalPoint4 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint4 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 4;   
        }
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint4 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint1) {
            totalPoint4 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 4;   
        }
        if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint4 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint1) {
            totalPoint4 = secondPoint;
            secondID = 4;   
        }
        //Find third value
        //1 is third
        if(totalPoint1 < totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 < totalPoint3 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint1 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 1;    
        }
        if(totalPoint1 < totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint1 < totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint1 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 1;    
        }
        if(totalPoint1 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 < totalPoint3 && totalPoint1 < totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint1 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 1;    
        }
        //2 is third
        if(totalPoint2 < totalPoint1 && totalPoint2 < totalPoint3 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 2;    
        }
        if(totalPoint2 < totalPoint1 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint2 < totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 2;    
        }
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint2 < totalPoint3 && totalPoint2 < totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 2;    
        }
        //3 is third
        if(totalPoint3 < totalPoint1 && totalPoint3 < totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 3;    
        }
        if(totalPoint3 < totalPoint1 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 < totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 3;    
        }
        if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint3 < totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 < totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 3;    
        }
        //4 is third.
        if(totalPoint4 < totalPoint1 && totalPoint4 < totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint4 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 4;    
        }
        if(totalPoint4 < totalPoint1 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 < totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint4 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 4;    
        }
        if(totalPoint4 > totalPoint1 && totalPoint4 < totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 < totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint4 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 4;    
        }
```

I expect this to work but firstly I think this is a very bad way of writing it, secondly it doesn't return my expected value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should not use so many "if" loops ,it's not a recommended practice.

Comment: My eyes hurts - its IFception!

Comment: I totally agree, I write python normally and I can see a lot ways around this problem. But I have no idea what to do with this tool at hand.

Comment: Why don't you make an array storing the scores of the players and sort it to find the highest one?

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought but I'm not allowed to use arrays on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You should nest your if statements

```
if(totalPoint1 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint1 > totalPoint4) {
    totalPoint1 = firstPoint;
    firstID = 1;    
    if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint3 && totalPoint2 > totalPoint4) {
        totalPoint2 = secondPoint;
        secondID = 2;    
        if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint3 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 1;    
        } else {
            totalPoint4 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 4;    
        }
    } else if(totalPoint3 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint3 > totalPoint4) {
        totalPoint3 = thirdPoint;
        secondID = 3;    
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint4) {
            totalPoint2 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 2;    
        } else {
            totalPoint4 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 4;    
        }
    } else if(totalPoint4 > totalPoint2 && totalPoint4 > totalPoint2) {
        totalPoint4 = thirdPoint;
        secondID = 4;    
        if(totalPoint2 > totalPoint3) {
            totalPoint2 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 2;    
        } else {
            totalPoint3 = thirdPoint;
            thirdID = 3;    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to assign `totalPoint1` value to `firstPoint` then it should be `firstPoint = totalPoint1` and not reversed

So the code should be:

```
firstPoint = totalPoint1;
.
.
.
.
thirdPoint = totalPoint4;
```